# Unable to translate contents in span in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, translation

I try to add translation for following line

```
<h3>List your property <span>for sale or rent</span></h3>
```

I have added translation for "List your property” and "for sale or rent" in my JSON file.But when I add translations it shows only "List your property” and "for sale or rent” text is not shown.

I'm using following code:

```
<h3 ng-show="lang == 'es'" 
    ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" 
    translate="LIST_YOUR_PROPERTY">
    <span ng-show="lang == 'es'" 
          ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" 
          translate="FOR_SALE_OR_RENT"></span>
</h3>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please provide some more code. There is no translation or "style" on your span you shown.

Comment: <h3 ng-show="lang == 'es'" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" translate="LIST_YOUR_PROPERTY"><span>for sale or rent</span></h3>              For the string <h3>List your property <span>for sale or rent</span></h3> I have added translations for "List your Property" only. I want to add translation for "for sale and rent" part too which is in span. How should I add it? I tried many ways but unable to do it.

Comment: This doesnt help. This is the code you allready provided. Please answer the question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What is your translation key for "List your property" & "for sale or rent" ?

Comment: "LIST_YOUR_PROPERTY":"Anote su propiedad",
  "FOR_SALE_OR_RENT":"Para la venta o alquiler",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your translation keys like its shown in the [ngTranslate documentation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api). Use the HTML Template binding for `LIST_YOUR_PROPERTY` so your value inside your `<h3></h3>` element doesnt get replaced by the translation string.

```
<h3>{{ 'LIST_YOUR_PROPERTY' | translate }}<span translate="FOR_SALE_OR_RENT"></span></h3>
```

Comment: @PoojaPotghan-Kadam Cheers, added an explanation why this happened.